# Company of Heroes 2: How is the artilery in compare to CoH1?

Tags: company-of-heroes-2

In CoH 1 the artilery was quite annoying, because it had high range (almoust over whole map) and could be fired quite frequently. If you build a bunker it could be destroyed by one artilery. Or your base could be attack by artilery whole game.

How is it in CoH 2 in comparison to CoH 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's far less an issue in coh2 I have never seen anyone go full artillery online. There are units with a large range but they cost a lot and need to be defended. Morters are common early game but not for attacking bases. It's much harder for people to turtle and spam artillery in coh2 so no one really does it.